# How android installs multiple pending updates to app?

Tags: android, google-play

My App is currently on version 0.0.1 and I have pushed two updates of my app to play store, 0.0.2 and 0.0.3.

So now when android updates my app, will it update 0.0.1 directly to 0.0.3 or the updates will be installed in the order of release or push.

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: @SohailZahid: Thanks for replying. The question was when android updated the app, will it update 0.0.1 version to directly 0.0.3 or it will update 0.0.1 to 0.0.2 and then 0.0.3? I got the answer below.

Comment: thats great try elaborate your query will give more understanding. Which answer help you you can vote them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: @Rotwang: As you wish. But I believe this question can help people in deciding their coding strategy. Earlier I designed my app upgrade strategy thinking play store upgrades incrementally but answer of this question helped me to correct it.

Comment: It's not a matter of wishes. This is not a question for this site. Since it doesn't involve any code.

Comment: Ok. Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play Store keeps only the copy of your latest version APK.
so when a user updates a version from 0.0.1, only the latest APK till that time is downloaded

So in your case **0.0.3 will be downloaded from Play Store and install**

Answer (score 0):

The application will be updated to the latest version skipping other updates. So your app will be updated from 0.0.1 to 0.0.3 directly